# AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox cannot be enabled after disabling

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AjaxControlToolkit ComboBox as follows:

```
<ATC:ComboBox
  id="cmbid1"
  runat="server"
  Width="150px"
  RenderMode="Block"
  DropDownStyle="DropDownList"
  AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend">
</ATC:ComboBox>
```

Elsewhere on the page, I have a checkbox that I want to use to toggle the ComboBox:

```
<asp:CheckBox
  ID="lockCheckBox"
  runat="server" 
  Text="Locked"
  Enabled="False" 
  OnCheckedChanged="lockCheckBox_CheckedChanged"
  AutoPostBack="True" />
```

Then I have a handler like this:

```
protected void lockCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lockCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        cmbid1.Enabled = false;

        EnableControlNotLockedDown();
    }
    else
    {
        cmbid1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Instead of toggling the ComboBox from enabled to disabled and vice versa, the ComoBox just gets disabled and never becomes enabled again.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to control a UI action like enabled/disabled on the server side? Wouldn't it be simpler if it is done with JavaScript?

Comment: @Dalorzo, you make a good point but everything is done on server side for this app.